# In a SQL database, how can I add a unique constraint that depends on a value in a foreign key linked table?

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite, unique-constraint

As an example, I have 2 tables:

```
devices
-----------------
id (Primary Key)
logical_address
physical_location (Foreign Key (physical_locations.id))
```

```
physical_locations
------------------
id (Primary Key)
name
district
```

As shown, the devices table references its location to the physical locations table.

What I need to do is enforce uniqueness of the logical_address column in the devices table but ONLY within the district associated with its location record.

So for example, consider these records:

```
physical_locations
----------------------
id  name      district
LA   loc_A     1
LB   loc_B     1
LC   loc_C     2
LD   loc_D     2
```

```
devices
----------------------
id  logical_address    physical_location
1   100                LA                 <-----this is okay, same district as 2 but different address
2   201                LB                 <-----this is okay, same district as 1 but different address
3   100                LC                 <-----this is also okay, same address as 1 but different district 
4   100                LD                 <-----this is NOT OKAY, same address AND same district as 3
```

I just don't know how to reference this column in a foreign key referenced table for a UNIQUE constraint. Alternatively, I am not sure how to structure my data to maintain this requirement without such an issue.

One thought I had was to create another logical_address table with address and district columnns, with a unique constraint on both  and simply reference device logical addresses to these entries with a unique constraint, but that introduces the same issue in another area. Then it is possible for a device to have a location with a district that does not match the district of the logical_address.

Is there a way to enforce this using a unique constraint or by restructuring my tables, or will I need something more advanced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common trick is to add a unique constraint to physical_locations:

```
create table physical_locations
( physical_location_id char(2) not null --  primary key
, name varchar(20) not null
, district int not null
, UNIQUE (district, physical_location_id)
);
```

Now it is possible to reference that in a foreign key (guarantees that the same location, district is used:

```
create table devices
( device_id int not null primary key
, logical_address int not null
, district int not null
, physical_location_id char(2) not null
,     foreign key (district, physical_location_id)
      references physical_locations (district, physical_location_id)
,     UNIQUE (logical_address, district)      
);

insert into physical_locations (physical_location_id, name, district)
values ('LA', 'la', 1)
     , ('LB', 'lb', 1)
     , ('LC', 'lc', 2)
     , ('LD', 'ld', 2);
```

Drawback is that you have to add district to devices:

```
insert into devices (device_id,logical_address, physical_location_id, district)
values (1, 100, 'LA', 1)
     , (2, 201, 'LB', 1)
     , (3, 100, 'LC', 2);
```

The unique constraint prevents duplicates:

```
insert into devices (device_id,logical_address, physical_location_id, district)
values (4, 100, 'LD', 2);

UNIQUE constraint failed: devices.logical_address, devices.district
```

As @ypercube noted in a comment, one needs to enable foreign keys with:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

If we try to fool the unique constraint by using another district, the foreign key will complain:

```
insert into devices (device_id,logical_address, physical_location_id, district)
values (4, 100, 'LD', 3);

FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=043b1bffda223e739995011df1fa64e4)

Comment: you need to enable foreign keys in SQLite with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e09e1b99363b51a866d4f64505d180f6

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was not aware of that

Comment: This makes sense and appears to work. It is unfortunate that it requires one to enter a district AND a location in the device record, since the location DETERMINES the district, but it definitely prevents incorrect data from being entered so I guess it's a small price to pay! Going to play around with this and see if it's really meeting my needs and there isn't a way to avoid that double-entry before I go with this one. Thanks!

Comment: This could typically be solved with a before trigger, example at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=23e79378e34fc53a7aac7c23e4a6f62e . But it appears as if before triggers can only be used to validate data in sqllite (unless ypercube has another pragma up his sleeves:-)

Comment: Another option is to validate the insert/update with triggers

Comment: After playing around with it, I ended up setting district as a column in devices and setting a unique constraint on (district, logical_address) as recommended. I did also end up creating a trigger to validate the device district matches the device location district.
This is what I ended up with: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=166aa8809b6f188ca425ae7205d6fe44
I'm sure there are better more performant ways to execute that trigger validation but this is the best I could come up with for now.

Comment: You don't really need the trigger (other than for a more intuitive message), if you drop the trigger the same inserts will fail. What I meant is that you could use a validation trigger instead of duplicating district, adding unique constraints etc. Major drawback is that you only know that the rows after you created the trigger is validated, the other approach should guarantee that all existing and future data is valid.